# Creating one single coverage polygon feature class from XY point data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, xy

I'm using ArcMap 10.2, and I need to map areas covered by London postcodes (E1 0xx, E1 1xx, E1 2xx, and so on). What I have is the coordinates for every single postcode (310,000 in total) in an Excel sheet, so I can create point feature classes, which I then want to group as explained above.

How can I create a polygon shapefile that will include a group of coordinates within E1 0xx postcode?

For example. I want that polygon shapefile to cover the are of those postcodes specifically. In the end I need to end up with multiple polygon shapefiles that will represent different Postcodes districts (E1 0xx, E1 1xx...).
Tried the Coverage tool, but it's not seem to be doing what I expected it to. Just installed XTools Pro, maybe that could help me.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your Question to describe what you mean by coverage, please?  I suspect that you are trying to get a tool working that will create output that is not what you are expecting.  The term coverage can mean an old Esri vector format, or a raster format (as in Web Coverage Service), and there may be other meanings too.

Comment: @PolyGeo - Just rephrased my question. I am afraid the Coverage Tool is not what I need. Was misguided by the standard meaning of coverage I think.

Comment: This layer does not already exist as a polygon layer (e.g. shapefile)?

Comment: What do you mean? I only have the set of point as a point shp with all the coordinates. Where would it already exist as a polygon shp?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly what may work for you, if you have an Advanced level license, is to use the [Create Thiessen Polygons](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/create-thiessen-polygons.htm) tool which:

> Creates Thiessen polygons from point features.
>
> Each Thiessen polygon contains only a single point input feature. Any
>   location within a Thiessen polygon is closer to its associated point
>   than to any other point input feature.

Once you have the polygons run an ArcPy update cursor through them to give each a postcode "stem" value that you can Dissolve on.