# Why isn't Generate (Coverage) Tool working?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, convert, arcgis-10.2, esri-coverage-format

I'm using ArcMap 10.2 and I have the Advanced Licence, but when I try running the Coverage (Toolbox) it does not seem to work.

Any advice on what is going wrong?

[image: nothing happens even if I double click on it]

I am trying to Generate Coverage. I've got there searching for **Coverage - Conversion - To Coverage - Generate. Nothing comes up even if I double click on it**

Comment: Would you clarify what happens when you run the tool please?

Comment: Nothing comes up really. I heard it could give you an error, but for me it simply does not open at all. I am meant to tick any extensions?

Comment: Can you supply a picture of how the icon for the tool and the Coverage toolbox look for you in ArcToolbox? What happens when you click twice on the tool? Any message?

Comment: What data are you trying to convert to a coverage?

Comment: Posted the picture below. Double clicking doesn't help either and nothing comes up still

Comment: @nmtoken trying to convert point feature class to a polygon covering the entire area. My previous question refers to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You don't have access to the Coverage toolbox (try opening ArcToolbox window instead and check if you have Coverage Tools there). Also check if you have C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\ArcToolbox\Toolboxes\Coverage Tools.tbx at place. In 10.0 at least you need to install ArcINFO Workstation to get access to the Coverage tools.

Comment: Your previous question is not part of this one so be sure to treat every Question you post as if it is the only one that you have posted.  The Generate (Coverage) tool converts an ASCII file in a particular format to coverage format.  Coverages started to go out of vogue about 15 years ago and are rarely seen nowadays - are you sure that is the format that you want to create?

Comment: @PolyGeo, - tried to link my previous question. Thought using Coverage would be a good solution, and that's why I was trying to see how I can run it.  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93134/how-create-one-single-coverage-polygon-feature-class-from-xy-point-data

Comment: For some reason, even when I run the Conversion tool straight from the toolbox - To Coverage - Feature Class to Coverage, the only output I get after it is another point feature class. Am I misunderstanding the word/tool Coverage?

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov the Coverage Toolboxes are in place. Managed to run straight from System Toolbox, but doesn't do what I wanted it to. Going on a limb here, but do you have any suggestion on what I can do for my previous question? 
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93134/how-create-one-single-coverage-polygon-feature-class-from-xy-point-data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the original question, [from here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_Coverage_toolbox/001300000001000000/), it states:

> If you do not have ArcInfo Workstation installed, the Coverage toolbox
> will not appear in the list of available toolboxes.

I understand your confusion - search shows it, but it doesn't open. If you expand the toolbox under System Toolboxes or the ArcToolbox window, you don't see the Coverage toolbox at the root level, correct? The search has been indexed with everything (including the Coverage toolbox, but it'll only work if ArcInfo Workstation is installed)

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your issue with 10.2, strange. But you can open the tool by right-clicking it in the Search results > Locate in Catalog > and then double-click it from the toolbox.

Comment: It doesn't take me anywhere. However, found the Conversion Tool (To Coverage) in the System Toolbox, but doesn't seem to do what I thought it would. Thanks for the help anyway